# Moving authentication to service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I'm writing simple CRUD-like MVC app at the moment, trying to learn proper N-tier architecture, and so far i had MVC which gets objects through WCF which call my Data Access layer to get those objects from Database.

However I just realized most likely huge mistake I'm making, I left all generated authentication stuff where it was - in MVC project except ApplicationUser and ApplicationDbContext which i moved to Business layer and Data Access layer accordingly and referenced them which I think defeats purpose of Service. How do I move properly authentication to service in this case? Perhaps there is a sample N-Tier project which has authentication moved to service and all?

So far my references are like this:
MVC client knows about Service(as service reference), Business layer
Service knows about Data Access, Business Layer
Data Access knows about Business layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might help you! this explains asp.net identity with Design Patterns
http://timschreiber.com/2015/01/14/persistence-ignorant-asp-net-identity-with-patterns-part-1/